# Want to call an api to get the data from mongodb in json format but getting in raw format, using javascript, node.js, express, mongodb

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, mongodb, express

*******This is how I'm connecting to the database:*******

```
> //Connecting Mongodb using mongoclient
> 
> const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
> 
> const url = 'url is used'
> 
> const dbName = 'virtualcso'
> 
> let db
> 
> // Conforming the database is connected
> 
> MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client) => {
> 
>   if (err) return console.log(err)
> 
>   // Storing a reference to the database so you can use it later
> 
>   db = client.db(dbName)
> 
>   console.log(`Connected MongoDB: ${url}`)
> 
>   console.log(`Database: ${dbName}`) })
```

***and this is the api calling***

```
> // api to fetch the data from the Mongodb
> 
>   app.get('/fetch', function (req, res) {
> 
>     // getting all the data
> 
>     db.collection('sectester_zap')
> 
>       .find()
> 
>       .toArray(function (err, items) {
> 
>         res.json(items);
> 
>       })   })
```

*****and this is how I'm getting the result*******

[{"_id":"600bc689bee1c602a89713d1","@version":"2.10.0","@generated":"Wed, 13 Jan 2021 20:21:56","site":[{"@name":"http://demo.testfire.net","@host":"demo.testfire.net","@port":"80","@ssl":"false","alerts":[{"pluginid":"10021","alertRef":"10021","alert":"X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing","name":"X-Content-Type-Options Header Missing","riskcode":"1","confidence":"2","riskdesc":"Low (Medium)","desc":"

The Anti-MIME-Sniffing header X-Content-Type-Options was not set to 'nosniff'. This allows older versions of Internet Explorer and Chrome to perform MIME-sniffing on the response body, potentially causing the response body to be interpreted and displayed as a content type other than the declared content type. Current (early 2014) and legacy versions of Firefox will use the declared content type (if one is set), rather than performing MIME-sniffing.

","instances":}}]}]

*****I need to get this data in json format******

Answer (score 0):

Without being well versed with MongoDB, by the looks of it you are getting the result as JSON and then you are putting it in an array.

And from what I can find looking around, .find() will return a cursor to all documents in a JSON format, so consider if you actually need to use .toArray() in your solution.

I looked among others here: https://www.guru99.com/mongodb-query-document-using-find.html
They are using in their example .forEach(printjson) to show their results.

Your example adding this to test the output would look like:

> // api to fetch the data from the Mongodb
>
> app.get('/fetch', function (req, res) {
>
> ```
> // getting all the data
>
> db.collection('sectester_zap')
>   .find()
>   .forEach(printjson)
> ```
>
> })